# Rails test deprecation warning

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails test introduced the following warning when I was testing my model. What modifications should I make to my model,

```
rake test test/models/user.rb
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your User.has_many :incoming_friends declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
. (called from <class:User> at /home/divya/projects/shufflejoy/app/models/user.rb:9)
```

and this is my user model,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
validates :user_name , :email, :first_name ,:last_name , :presence => true
has_many :invitations
has_many :incoming_friends , :class_name => "User" , :foreign_key=>"friend_id" , :through => :invitations, :conditions => ["status = 1"]
has_many :outgoing_friends , :class_name => "User" , :foreign_key=>"user_id", :through => :invitations, :conditions => ["status = 1"]

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your association conditions as callable objects. Like so:

```
has_many :incoming_friends, -> { where(:status => '1') }, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id", :through => :invitations
has_many :outgoing_friends, -> { where(:status => '1') }, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id", :through => :invitations
```

More info at the official Rails docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many

Comment: I already tried this, but it throws the following syntax error

 syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
...tgoing_friends, -> { :status => '1' }, :class_name => "User"...

Comment: I'm using `where` inside the block, you seem to have missed that.

Comment: Yup. The callable object needs to be a valid ActiveRecord scope.

Comment: I got that, Thanks. but when I run the default test, 

' 1) Error:
UserTest#test_the_truth:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_users_on_email': INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`) VALUES ('2014-02-01 17:45:51', '2014-02-01 17:45:51', 298486374)'

Comment: If you want to ask a second question, please open up a different question.